# How to connect mobile app using node js to a remote mysql database on Godaddy cPanel?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ionic-framework

> <-- ErrorPacket { fieldCount: 255,   errno: 1045,   sqlStateMarker:
>   '#',   sqlState: '28000',   message: 'Access denied for user
>   \'eazy_db\'@\'122.179.102.170\' (using password: YES)' }
>
> Problem with MySQLError: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for
>   user 'eazy_db'@'122.179.102.170' (using password: YES)

Getting this error when node server is started. 122.179.102.170 is the router ip address instead of my server ip address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you can SSH into your server that is hosting your DB, type in the following Linux command to get your server's IP Address:  `ifconfig`
- The response from that command will look like this:
  [image: Output of ifconfig command]
- Notice the `eth0` block.  I highlighted it in a blue box.
- That is the I.P. address of your MySQL server.

If you cannot SSH into the server that is hosting your MySQL database, I recommend following these steps and obtaining the Database Host name from the GoDaddy Console:  [Setting up an Access Database for Your Hosting Account](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/34/setting-up-an-access-database-for-your-hosting-account)